# Asynchronous Generic Responses From Api

Tags: c#, multithreading, api, generics, asynchronous

I'm trying to create a universal return type for my API that can run with concurrency. I was originally using HttpResponseMessages across the board since they allow me to use any status code while throwing in any type of object I want. However, it had no type safety and really no threading opportunities.  I found an article a few days ago (I don't have the link anymore, sorry) that showed the a possibility of inheriting IHttpActionResult so I took that thought and ran:

```
public class ApiResponse<TReturnType> : IHttpActionResult
{
    public TReturnType Contents { get; }
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; }
    public bool IsAsync { get; }
    private Task<TReturnType> AsyncContents { get; }
    private HttpRequestMessage Request { get; }

    public ApiResponse(TReturnType content, HttpStatusCode statusCode, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        Contents = content;
        Request = request;
        StatusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public ApiResponse(Task<TReturnType> asyncContent, HttpStatusCode statusCode, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        AsyncContents = asyncContent;
        Request = request;
        StatusCode = statusCode;
        IsAsync = true;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (IsAsync)
        {
            return AsyncContents.ContinueWith(t => Request.CreateResponse(StatusCode, t), cancellationToken);
        }

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(StatusCode, Contents);

        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

Furthermore, I created a base API controller class where I could implement the construction of these new return types:

```
public class ClaimsApiController : ApiController
{
    public ApiResponse<TResponseType> CreateResponse<TResponseType>(HttpStatusCode statusCode, TResponseType contents)
    {
        return new ApiResponse<TResponseType>(contents, statusCode, Request);
    }

    public ApiResponse<TResponseType> CreateAsyncResponse<TResponseType>(HttpStatusCode statusCode, Task<TResponseType> asyncContents)
    {
        return new ApiResponse<TResponseType>(asyncContents, statusCode, Request);
    }
}
```

I was hoping that this would allow controllers to return an object asynchronously if they chose to. The option still remained if they didn't need it.

The problem I'm having is knowing whether this will be efficient enough to be used for a large scale API or even whether this works at all. I'm very new to threading and async things so I hope this isn't very obvious to everyone else but me.

I had another thought to remove the IsAsync flag and always return the response and handle the threading differently in the creation method using:

```
public async Task<ApiResponse<TResponseType>> CreateAsyncResponse<TResponseType>(Task<TResponseType> asyncContents)
{
    TResponseType contents = await asyncContents;
    var tmp = new ApiResponse<TResponseType>(contents, HttpStatusCode.OK, Request);
    return tmp;
}
```

If any of you experts can help me decide which path would be best, I would be very appreciative.

**EDIT:**

I'm sorry my question was too broad. I thought I had explained things rather down to the point but let me try again.

My API will be returning tasks in *some* places of the API. I would like it to eventually be all places. For instance I have an endpoint that looks like:

```
public Task<StatResults<MyObject>> Search(long id)
{
    return _searchLogic.Search(id);
}
```

This function does exactly as explained: it returns the task of stat results for that type of object. My API is getting pretty convoluted with what could be hundreds of different types objects being returned.

With my implementation explained above I would go one of these routes:

```
public ApiResponse<StatResults<MyObject>> Search(long id)
{
    // This calls the CreateAsyncResponse in the second code section.
    return CreateAsyncResponse(_searchLogic.Search(id));
}
```

Or:

```
public async Task<ApiResponse<StatResults<MyObject>>> Search(long id)
{
    // This calls the CreateAsyncResponse in just above the Edit
    return await CreateAsyncResponse(_searchLogic.Search(id));
}
```

So my question is exactly this: I'm not at the point of async expertise yet to know which method would be more optimized in a large scale API. I was hoping that someone at stack overflow would be able to tell me if using .ContinueWith() would be just as good as awaiting the object then returning a new task or which way to go.

I hope this is more simplified for you all. Let me know what else I can give you.

Comment: Your second options seems entirely superior. Having the general response type itself know _anything_ about asynchronous behavior sounds like a recipe for confusing and inelegant code. That said, lacking a _specific_ scenario with a good [mcve] to illustrate it, the question itself is fairly broad, answerable only in vague generalities or with extensive discussion.